# Python, requests и авторизация на сайте. Как передать логин и пароль (application/x-protobuf)

Tags: python, requests, авторизация, google-protobuf

Есть некий сайт, авторизация на котором идет в несколько этапов: сначала необходимо получить csrf-токен, далее необходимо передать логин и пароль, а также csrf-токен в headers и в куках.

Пример кода:

```
import requests

PAYLOAD = {'Логин', 'Пароль'}
twofauth_page = "/twofactor-auth"

headers["x-csrftoken"] = csrf
headers["content-type"] = "application/x-protobuf"
headers["accept"] = "*/*"
cookie['csrftoken'] = csrf

client = requests.session()
req = requests.Request('POST', base_url + twofauth_page, data=PAYLOAD)
req.headers = headers
req.cookies = cookie
response = client.send(req)
```

[image: Post-data запроса]

Данный код в принципе работает, но с валидными логином и паролем сайт отвечает "Неправильный логин или пароль". Проблема похоже в том, что PAYLOAD передается в запросе как "Логин=Пароль",
а из браузера он отправляется как "Логин\0х12\0х0ВПароль", т.е. без знака "=". Как это побороть?

UPD: Это оказался Google protobuf. Решил ))))

Сделал файл msg.proto

```
syntax = 'proto2';
message payload {
 required string login = 1;
 required string password = 2;
}
```

далее командой
`protoc --python_out=. ./msg.proto`
получил msg_pb2.py
Работающий код в итоге:

```
import requests
import msg_pb2

payload = msg_pb2.payload()
payload.login = 'LOGIN'
payload.password = 'PASSWORD'
PAYLOAD = payload.SerializeToString(payload)

twofauth_page = "/twofactor-auth"

headers["x-csrftoken"] = csrf
headers["content-type"] = "application/x-protobuf"
headers["accept"] = "*/*"
cookie['csrftoken'] = csrf

client = requests.session()
req = requests.Request('POST', base_url + twofauth_page, data=PAYLOAD)
req.headers = headers
req.cookies = cookie
response = client.send(req)
```

Жаль, что это только часть процесса авторизации...

UPD2:
Можно проще, SerializeToString выдает:
b'\n\x05login\x12\x0bsecret_pass'
где
`\x05` - длина логина (hex)
`\x12` - разделитель
`\x0b` - длина пароля (hex)

Comment: "некий сайт"... адрес дайте? ;)

Comment: Ну так передайте с этими байтами как бинарный поток. Кстати, а какая кодировка-то этих login/password? Может в этом дело? И да, 0xb12 не зарезервирован, а 0x120b (не верю я, что там UCS2BE, но всё же) из Эфиопского алфавита...

Comment: >И да, 0xb12 не зарезервирован, а 0x120b (не верю я, что там UCS2BE, но всё >же) из Эфиопского алфавита
Спасибо за наводку, проверил, оказалось, что эти байты меняются, т.е. структура сообщения такая: 11 байт (заголовок?) + Логин + 2 байта (разделитель?) + Пароль

Comment: Для 4-х пар логин/пароль заголовок и разделитель разный.